# python numpy image arrays: Take a list of horizontally concatenated images and arrange them in a grid

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, 3d

I am trying to take a list of images from a source folder and put them together in a 2x2 grid, with some text underneath each image.

My code so far can scan a folder, add the appropriate text under each image, add a border, and display the images in a line, I'll omit that for brevity. I am making them all a line because later down the line I want to extend it to further grid sizes, so my theory was all images into a big line, then sort into a grid afterwards:

[image]

This line of images is a numpy array, concatenated together like so:

```
images_line = np.hstack( (np.asarray(i) for i in list_images_with_text ) )

print(images.ndim)  > 3
print(images.size)  > 1326000
print(images.shape) > (325, 1360, 3)
```

I have tried numpy's images.reshape() to take the array and turn it into a 2x2 grid of images ie:

ASIMOV     DOOM

DUNKIRK   METALLICA

```
single_width = horiz_img_size;
single_height = vert_img_size + info_box_height;
images = images.reshape(2*single_height,2*single_width,3)
```

but that didn't quite work out right:[image]

I feel like I am close, but I can't quite get my head around 3d arrays. I'd like to extend this to more grid sizes, 4x4, 5x5, 5x4, etc. User-enterable if possible.

Here is a minimum reproducible example if you download the original image

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import PIL
from PIL import Image

single_width = 340
single_height = 325

im=Image.open('TDYZ0.jpg')
images = np.asarray(im)

images = images.reshape(2*single_height,2*single_width,3) # not quite right

images = PIL.Image.fromarray(images)
images.save('outImage.png')
```

Thanks all

Comment: If you want it extensible, you probably want to keep your list of images `[np.asarray(i) for i in list_images_with_text]` and then play around with them using [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it how I want with the following, but Im not sure how to make it extendable/loopable `images = np.block([[[list_images_with_text[0]],[list_images_with_text[1]]],[[list_images_with_text[2]],[list_images_with_text[3]]]])`

Answer (score 0):

For a MxN tiling of the images, perhaps you could try (I haven't tested):

```
images = images.reshape(M, N, single_height, single_width, 3)
```

So, for the 2x2 that you showed the output for, it would be:

```
images = images.reshape(2, 2, single_height, single_width, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've ended up with a 5d array here of (2,2,325,340,3), which PIL.Image.fromarray(images) doesn't know how to handle. I'm unsure what to do from here

Comment: @WillHaward -- I realize now that an understanding of `PIL.Image.fromarray()` is important here -- which I don't have at all. For example, one relevant question would be - does `fromarray()` expect only a 1-D array of `h x w` images, or does it also accept an `M x N` array of `h x w` images? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, albeit in a disgusting fashion. A string is built to form the correct heirarchy of np.block() commands, then is executed . Building on Daniel F's comment:

```
M = 2
N = 2
string = "images = np.block([["
maxpos = numfiles-1;
pos = 0;
try:
    for j in range(0, N):
        for i in range(0, M):
            if pos > maxpos:
                string+= f"[np.asarray(null_image)],"
            else:
                string += f"[list_images_with_text[{pos}]]"
                pos=pos+1
                if i < M-1:
                    string+=f","
        if j < N-1:
            string+=f"],["
    string+="]])"
except:
   print("oops")
exec(string);
```